# How to copy or mirror one dir to another?

Tags: linux

tried

```
cp -avr /home/uname/test /home/uname/dev 
rsync -av /home/uname/test /home/uname/dev
```

What i want is for /dev to be identical to /test, not have a copy of /test inside /dev.

Comment: Try your rsync command with slashes at the ends of both paths.

Comment: sweet.  make that an answer and I'll change my accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure dev does not exist.

```
rm -rf /home/uname/dev
```

then copy to contents from test into dev

```
cp -rfp /home/uname/test /home/uname/dev
```